# plupload 2 doesnt trigger camera in html5 runtime on ipad

Tags: html, ipad, plupload

I have an application which works on android tablets and prompts camera when browse button is clicked which is fine, but using Ipad i wanted to do same but instead it prompts gallery not camera. I am using html5 runtime.
Note: Ipad prompts camera in html4 runtime, but the image rotates with this runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, set  multi_selection:false, this will allow you too capture cam from ipad /iphone